# How to exit a process after disown

Tags: linux, ssh, background-process

I use `disown` to run long-running process via SSH. For example I run the following program:

```
vmd -e script.tcl > out.txt &
```

Then I use `disown -a` to deattach it from the shell. When I reconnect the terminal the `out.txt` shows that the program has finished. However, it shows the command prompt of the vmd (`vmd>`). VMD is a program for running TCL scripts for chemistry simulations. You can assume it is something like python with its own shell

http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/vmd/tutorial-html/node8.html

After a while, I couldn't connect to ssh because of the limit on the running processes (`fork retry: Resource temporary unavailable`). 
First, I want to know how I can kill those disowned processes if they are in waiting state.

Second, I want to know if I exit the `vmd` program by putting `exit` at the end of my `script.tcl`, would it resolve the problem above for future uses?

Comment: `vmd` ain't a tool I ever heard about. Without some information about what that tool is, I don't think this question can be answered.

Comment: These days, I would prefer to run this inside a `screen` or `tmux` session and not fiddle around with `disown` etc.

Comment: @kasperd I modified my question.

Comment: @Sven I can't run `screen` via SSH, the command is not found. I use MobaXTerm to connect the server.

Comment: @Ahmad Then just install it.

Comment: @kasperd I am not the admin of the server, just a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Is More Than One Way To Do It. (TM)

Solution 1 (probably the best): add the command to exit `vmd` to the end of your script.

Solution 2: redirect standard input of the `vmd` command to (or from, depending on your mindset) the null device, like so:

```
vmd -e script.tcl > out.txt < /dev/null &
```

That way when `vmd` is done with your script and tries to read the next command from standard input it will receive "end of file" and exit.

Solution 3: Kill the left over `vmd` process with `kill`. You'll need its PID for that which you can either note as the shell prints it after starting it with `&`, or find through the command `ps ax`. Try `kill -TERM` (the default) first, if that doesn't work use `kill -HUP`. Do **not** use `kill -KILL` aka `kill -9`.

Solution 4: Use `screen` or `tmux` instead of `disown`. That way you can reconnect to the running `vmd` process and enter further commands like `exit`.